# CSS Transparency Bug

Tags: html, css

Why Is the article transparent? I tried looking through the web to find anything similar but I'm surprised not to have found anything and I don't really know what to do, I'm Baffled.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #FFF8E7 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #FFF8E7 87.5%, #FFF8E7), linear-gradient(150deg, #FFF8E7 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #FFF8E7 87.5%, #FFF8E7), linear-gradient(30deg, #FFF8E7 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #FFF8E7 87.5%, #FFF8E7), linear-gradient(150deg, #FFF8E7 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #FFF8E7 87.5%, #FFF8E7), linear-gradient(60deg, #FFF8E777 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #FFF8E777 75%, #FFF8E777), linear-gradient(60deg, #FFF8E777 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #FFF8E777 75%, #FFF8E777);
  background-size: 44px 77px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 22px 39px, 22px 39px, 0 0, 22px 39px;
}

article {
  background-color: #FFF8E7;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Cosmic Latte</h1>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your body has an opacity of 0.8. This affects all child elements.**

In case you don't want your article to be transparent, remove the opacity from the body and change all color values for background-color and background-image, e.g. instead of *background-color: #000000;* you can use *background-color: #000000CC;* or *background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);* .